# Internal Server Error on mouse hover on the Recent Items

Tags: visualforce, home-page-component

Whenever i tried to see the snapshot of the recent items on the left panel of the Home page and when i mouse hover it displays "Internal Server Error". I do not know why this is happening. Please see the screen shot below.

[image]